# Condition IF In Power Query's Advanced Editor

Tags: excel, if-statement, powerbi, powerquery

I have a field named `field`, and I would like to see if it is null, but I get an error in the query, my code is this:

```
let
    Condition= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="test_table"]}[Content],
    field= Condition{0}[fieldColumn],
    query1="select * from students",
    if field <> null then query1=query1 & " where id = '"& field &"',
    exec= Oracle.Database("TESTING",[Query=query1])
in
    exec
```

but I get an error in the condition, do you identify the mistake?
I got `Expression.SyntaxError: Token Identifier expected.`

Comment: If you'd like to read more about Power Query's programming language (M), we have a getting started guide on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt299038.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to assign the if line to a variable. Each M line needs to start with an assignment:

```
let
Condition= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="test_table"]}[Content],
field= Condition{0}[fieldColumn],
query1="select * from students",
query2 = if field <> null then query1 & " some stuff" else " some other stuff",
exec= Oracle.Database("TESTING",[Query=query2])
in
exec
```

In query2 you can build the select statement. I simplified it, because you also have conflicts with the double quotes.

Comment: @SergeyLossev -- you edited this 17 month old answer to change a single space? Get real, man! Stop hunting brownie points. Do something useful instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for:

```
if Not IsNull(field) then ....
```

Some data types you may have to check using IsEmpty() or 'field is Not Nothing' too. Depending on the datatype and what you are using.

To troubleshoot, it's best to try to set a breakpoint and locate where the error is happening and watch the variable to prevent against that specific value.

Comment: not yet, I continue having: Expression.SyntaxError: Token Identifier expected.

Comment: this sounds like a query formatting issue, not an excel issue. I know sql, but this is outside of my expertise.

Comment: I din't think so, cause I can add the query manually and it runs, it must be smthing of sintaxis in Power query, where Im not so strong

Comment: It seems like you're trying to run the query via a 'parameterized list', however you're building it as a single fixed string without a dynamic parameter. So maybe the call to the Oracle.Database is incorrect?

Comment: The query language Pablo is using is Power Query (M), which tends to be different than other languages. `Not` and `IsNull` aren't part of the M language, the right way to check for null is `field <> null`

Answer (score 0):

To meet this requirement, I would build a fresh Query using the PQ UI to select the students table/view from Oracle, and then use the UI to Filter the [id] column on any value.

Then in the advanced editor I would edit the generated FilteredRows line using code from your Condition + field steps, e.g.

`FilteredRows  = Table.SelectRows(TESTING_students, each [id] = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="test_table"]}{0}[fieldColumn])`

This is a minor change from a generated script, rather than trying to write the whole thing from scratch.